# Navigate tabs in MacOS Preview

Tags: macos, macbook, tabs, preview.app

Is it possible to navigate between the tabs in macOS Preview program as one does in Safari, with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd>? This doesn't seem to work for me, and after trying other combinations couldn't also get this functionality.

I'm in a MacBook Pro retina early 2015 running Mojave 10.14.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not [yet] fully system-wide behaviour to have  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>[num]</kbd>    for direct selection.

Most Apps, including Preview, still use a simple step left/right structure [Safari follows this as well as direct selection]

<kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>   or
 <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you mean by 'tabs'; but if you mean between windows in Preview, you might want to try <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd>

Comment: Not windows, that's completely covered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app), individual tabs within a single window.